# Retrieve variables from a HTML page into a .aspx page

Tags: javascript, c#, html, ms-access

I am currently making a game in HTML/javascript, and at the end of the game the user is asked to input their name into a textbox and press save score. Is it possible to get the data on the inside of the text box and the score that is saved in a variable onto the .aspx page to save into my database?

Comment: Sure when you post a form or make an Ajax call to the server

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible you have to get the values and post to asp sever side so that you can save it in database.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on("submit", "#form", saveData);
});

function saveData(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'targetPage.aspx',
        data: {name: $("#inputName").val(), score: scoreVariable},
        success: alert("Score Saved")
    });
}
```